# How can I directly respond to NSTableView edits while still using NSArrayController?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

In my Cocoa app, I have a sheet with a one-column `NSTableView` that lists a bunch of files in a directory (the app makes back-ups of it's main database, provides this list to users so they can revert to a particular back-up). The content is loaded into and provided to the table view by an `NSArrayController`, each object is just an `NSFileWrapper` (I'm considering using NSURL instead, but I digress). The NSArrayController handles sorting, enabling the buttons when a row is selected via bindings, that's all great. I have an `NSWindowController` subclass object (`BackupsSheetController`) that hooks all this up and exists in the sheet's nib.

However, when a user edits one of the cells, I want to respond to that change from `BackupsSheetController` by appropriately re-naming the file represented by that cell, putting it in its new location. Since the table view is bound to the NSArrayController, I don't get sent the `NSTableViewDataSource` message `– tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:`. If I set my BackupsSheetController as the datasource for the NSTableView object in the nib, I get sent that message *sometimes*, but not very often, to say nothing of every time.

Most questions and examples I see out there for this scenario handle this all by using a custom model class for items in their table view, and make some controller object an observer for changing properties that they wish to respond to. In other words, each item would be something like a BackupNode object, and BackupsSheetController would observe each for changes to the `name` property (or whatever I would call it). That seems totally overkill for my scenario, but I also don't want to ditch the bindings I've already got in use and I don't see another way to do this. Is there another way to do this, to make sure I reliably get the `setObject:...` message? Or should I drop the NSArrayController and make BackupsSheetController the delegate and datasource for the table?

Answer (score 2):

In the "BackupNode" scenario, I don't see why `BackupsSheetController` would observe each for changes in its name.  That's a very roundabout way of doing things.  I would think that the hypothetical `BackupNode` object would simply do the necessary work in its setter for the `name` property.

Anyway, I recommend using proper model objects. When you try to build a model with only Cocoa-provided objects like `NSFileWrapper`, `NSURL`, or `NSMutableDictionary`, you end up doing more work in the long run than if you just make a proper model object.

On a tangential topic, why is your window controller in the NIB? It should be the thing which loads (and owns) the NIB, which of course requires that it exist prior to the NIB being loaded, which means it can't be instantiated in the NIB.

Comment: On the tangent: the owner of the nib is my NSDocument subclass which loads it from nib and presents it as a sheet. The 'controller' object exists to handle the sheet's actions, bind to its objects, and keep that stuff off my document subclass, which can grow pretty large. Certainly open to other ideas there!

Comment: > "Anyway, I recommend using proper model objects."

You and me both, I just hadn't been thinking of the backups as models, I was being obtuse, I suppose ;-)